# XSLT Variables does not have any Values back

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have declare 2 Variables and fill them with chooses. I want to check them after that with ifs but I only gat two errors and I don't know where they from.

I tried to change the if statements but nothing works.

```
        <root>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiPfad'">
                    <xsl:variable name="Con1">
                        2001
                    </xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="Con1">
                        2000
                    </xsl:variable>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiName'">
                    <xsl:variable name="Con2">
                        2001
                    </xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="Con2">
                        2000
                    </xsl:variable>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="$Con1 == 2001 and $Con2 == 2001">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                    2001
                </xsl:processing-instruction>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$Con1 == 2000 and $Con2 == 2000">
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                    2000
                </xsl:processing-instruction>
            </xsl:if>
        </root>
```

I expect that the IF result will give me 2000 or 2001 as a Condition State which I need in my process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are scoped to the block in which they are declared, which means in your case they only exist in the `xsl:when` (and `xsl:otherwise`) blocks, and are not accessible outside that.

What you can do, is put the `xsl:choose` inside the `xsl:variable` instead

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:variable name="Con1">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiPfad'">2001</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>2000</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Con2">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiName'">2001</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>2000</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$Con1 = 2001 and $Con2 = 2001">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                2001
            </xsl:processing-instruction>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$Con1 = 2000 and $Con2 = 2000">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                2000
            </xsl:processing-instruction>
        </xsl:if>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, in the example you have shown, you don't really need the `xsl:variable` at all...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:if test="Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiPfad' and Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiName'">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                2001
            </xsl:processing-instruction>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiPfad') and not(Request/Query/Parameter = 'DateiName')">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="ConditionState">
                2000
            </xsl:processing-instruction>
        </xsl:if>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: wow xD it was just so easy ... i am ashamed ... i would bury myself now :D what ever xD Thanks

Comment: Do also note your XSLT had a syntax error in, as you were doing `$Con1 == 2000` (with two equals) instead of `$Con1 = 2000`